# Can't find directx library

Tags: directx

I recently installed windows 8 and installed directx sdk jun 2010 on it. However when I try to start a program on it gives me an error:

**Error**:
"couldnt find d3dx9.lib" or  "couldnt find d3dx11.h"

This error was in directx own sample projects also. I found an article on the internet that said these kind of libraries(every thing with x in it :d) are not supported any more. I commented all code that needed these libraries, it worked and my program ran.

**Question**:

What is it and how should I work with it? Are all these libraries are not supported? I found vs 2012 added a new framework:
direct 3d app and direct 2d app. I made a project in it but I hardly could understand the code and how it works. Is it a new way of working with directx or is the best to make an empty project?

Comment: where did you program come from? directx sdk samples or windows 8 sdk samples?

Comment: i really oppened my last proggrams in win 8 but it didnt run. even directx samples didnt run. but after removing d3dx11.h and removing d3dx11.lib first samples worked. i can just say this

Comment: There is a collection of these older DirectX SDK samples that have been cleaned up to remove legacy dependencies (such as D3DX11) so they build with just the Windows 8.x SDK that comes with VS 2012 / 2013. They are on [MSDN Code Gallery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to include the libraries you need into your projects settings.

**Right click the project** -> **Properties** -> **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependence** -> **Add the libraries your compiler is asking for**

Comment: really i know it. it says it cant find it. something like there is no such thing. all the lib and include are in the address but for example it finds d3d11.lib but cant find d3dx.lib and there is a error for it

Comment: @virtouso Interesting, try and see if you can locate the `.lib` files in your directx library folder.